# how to scp between two servers that share same .pem

Tags: linux, ssh, file-transfer, scp

I have two server which I use same `.pem` file to connect to them.

.pem file is only available on my local machine

I can transfer from/to local machine to either of those server but I can't transfer between those two servers without using my local machine as a bridge

basically I want to do something like this(obviously this won't work):

```
scp -i my.pem user@server1:/home/user/myFile user@server2:/home/user
```

Is there a way to do this?

**NOTE:**
 I want to avoid using `-3` as I don't really want to send data to go through local machine at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> scp -i my.pem user@server1:/home/user/myFile user@server2:/home/user
> ```

To do this, you would need authentication key (pem) to have also on the `server1`.

If this is not intended (it should not) and the machines are trusted to some point, you can use `ssh-agent`. You can add your pem key to the agent and then forward authentication socket to `server1`, which will allow you to authenticate from `server1` to `server2`. Something like this should make it:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add my.pem
scp -oForwardAgent=yes user@server1:/home/user/myFile user@server2:/home/user
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get `Host key verification failed.
lost connection
`

Comment: alright mate, it did work, I however need to go to server1 and do a dummy connection( ssh user@server2) it failed to connect, then go back to localmachine and retried what you said, then it worked...